# Change another element style on current element hover event

Tags: svg, hover

I am trying to show a tooltip when hovering over an svg element. To do this I am trying to use the `<set />` tag when creating my elements.

I know it is possible to change the current element's attributes on another element's events. Is the inverse possible? Changing another element's attribute on the current element's mouse events?

```css
body {
    background-color: #EEE;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card {
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    padding: 2em;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222;
}

.pie-center {
    background: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle1 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: teal;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 30 70;
}

.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
        <script src="conic-gradient.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <svg class="pie-center" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
                    <circle class="circle1" r="15.915494309" cx="20" cy="20">
                        <set attributeName="change-me.visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="mouseover" end="mouseout" />
                        <div class="tooltip">
                            <span id="change-me" class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
                        </div>
                    </circle>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I am trying to change the `visibility` property on my tooltip when the `mouseover` event happens on the circle. Is this possible?

Comment: A div element cannot be a child of a circle element. That's your main issue. change-me.visibility is wrong too. The attributeName is visibility.

Comment: Well that explains that. Any other way to achieve what I'm after? Or better yet, is there a way to style the `<title />` tag?

Comment: _use foreignObject and parent it properly._ can you please elaborate on what that means?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to look it up on my own. I don't see how that helps me achieve a tooltip on hover of an svg element

Comment: Really? how about my answer then. It uses a foreignObject as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the SMIL and the made it display. Note you can only apply SMIL to SVG elements which is why I've targeted the foreignObject element and not an html element as you did.

For some reason you've rotated the whole SVG so the text in the tooltip is rotated too. I'll leave you to deal with that.

```css
body {
    background-color: #EEE;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card {
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    padding: 2em;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222;
}

.pie-center {
    background: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle1 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: teal;
    stroke-width: 7;
    stroke-dasharray: 30 70;
}

.tooltiptext {
    font-size: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
        <script src="conic-gradient.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <svg class="pie-center" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
                    <circle id="c" class="circle1" r="15.915494309" cx="20" cy="20">
                    </circle>
                    <set href="#fo" attributeName="visibility" to="visible" begin="c.mouseover" end="c.mouseout" />
                    <foreignObject id="fo" visibility="hidden" x="15" width="100" height="100" pointer-events="none">
                        <div class="tooltip">
                            <span id="change-me" class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
                        </div>
                    </foreignObject>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to make use of the **default** tooltip, you can simply set a `<title>` element as a child of the circle. By default, this will only appear on hover:

```css
body {
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222;
}

.pie-center {
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: teal;
  stroke-width: 7;
  stroke-dasharray: 30 70;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
  <script src="conic-gradient.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <svg class="pie-center" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
        <circle class="circle1" r="15.915494309" cx="20" cy="20">
          <title class="tooltip">Tooltip</title>
        </circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I know about the `<title />` attribute, I have that in my app currently. But I want it to be styled. I can't style the `<title />` tag to save my life (spent 5 hours on it today). So I'm trying to roll my own styled tooltip.